# Proof that Cyril of Alexandria is a Saint in the Roman Catholic Church?

Tags: catholicism, saint, doctor, cyril-of-alexandria

If one checks the *Wikipedia* entry on [Cyril of Alexandria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyril_of_Alexandria), there is no indication that he is venerated as a Saint in the Roman Catholic Church.  But, although it is not indicated there, I am under the impression that (somehow) he is venerated as a Saint in the Byzantine Catholic Church, one of the 23 Eastern rites in full communion with Rome.

But, of course, (Saint) Cyril of Alexandria has been declared one of the thirty-six doctors of the Roman Catholic Church. See, for instance, the [chronological list of the doctors of the church](https://uscatholic.org/articles/200807/chronological-list-of-the-doctors-of-the-church/).

QUESTION: Has (Saint) Cyril of Alexandria ever been canonized (or officially recognized as a Saint) by the *Roman Catholic Church?* If not, how is it possible that he was proclaimed a Doctor of the Church by Pope Leo XIII in 1882?

Comment: For canonizations since 1594 you can check [this archive](https://www.causesanti.va/it/celebrazioni/canonizzazioni.html), for earlier see [_Martyrologium Romanum_](https://www.liturgialatina.org/martyrologium/00.htm).

Comment: @OrangeDog Thank you for these two links.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you got your information wrong, since although the Catholic church didn't commemorate Saint Cyril until 1882 (on Feb 9, later moved to June 27), Cyril was *already* listed as Saint in the 1583 [*Roman Martyrology*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_Martyrology) (see *Wikipedia* article [List of Catholic Saints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Catholic_saints#Catholic_saints)) and in the famous 4 volume compendium [Butler's Lives of The Saints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alban_Butler#The_Lives_of_Saints) (first published 1756-1759, Cyril's entry [here](https://archive.org/details/ButlersLivesOfTheSaintsCompleteEdition/page/n313/mode/2up?view=theater)).

While I cannot yet find more definite year of Cyril's recognition as saint, it is very probable that he was canonized before the animosity between East and West began.

Comment: The Roman Martyrology suffices to answer this question. +1